# Como listar todos os arquivos não adicionados (untracked files) no GIT?

Tags: git

Como faço para listar todos os arquivos não adicionados no commit no `git`?

Seria importante ter essa listagem para eu saber quando fazer um `git add` em arquivos específicos.

**Observação**: Utilizo o `git` pela linha de comando, pois o meu sistema operacional é o Ubuntu.

Comment: Estás a falar de `git status`?

Comment: `git status` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você consegue visualizar os arquivos que tiveram modificações pelo comando:

```
 git status
```

Esse comando exibe arquivos modificados e arquivos que serão adicionados ao repositório.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Untracked**

O untracked mostra somente os arquivos que ainda não fazem parte do seu repositório ou seja foram criados depois que você realizou o `pull` no projeto e realizou modificações.

Answer (score 4):

Outra maneira de fazer a listagem de arquivos marcados como `untracked` seria:

```
git status --untracked
```

Ou ainda

```
git status -u
```

Answer (score 3):

Usa `git status`

Documentacao: [`status`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status)